# Can i inject a Singleton-DependencyInjected object in multiples areas in a Blazor client application?

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor

I have a Blazor application where i am injecting a class (NotificationClass) to the MainLayout.razor.

The NotificationClass has a Errors string property. My goal is to using this class to bind to some component so i can show an errors that occur in any area of the client application. The ultimate idea is to show a Toast notification when an error occurs.

But so far this doesnt appear to be working.

**Question**
Is it possible to inject a singleton instance to different areas of the application?

If so, i think i need to implement a Changed event so i can invoke StateHasChanged in the MainLayout.razor.

**Resolved**

> I was able to resolve this myself by doing exactly what i suspected. I
>   raised an event which is handled by MainLayout. On that
>
> > event handled, i invoke this.StateHasChanged().

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a singleton, get the object via DI on several components, and raise and listen events on that components. I use this, for example, to show a Toast: any component can raise an event with toast text and main layout listen the event and shows the toast.

Important:

- Remember to implement `IDisposable` on `MainLayout` to release the event subscription when component disposes.
- Call `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` to update UI because changes are made via event.